# Printing parts of certain lines

Tags: text-processing

I want to read a file and print all lines that contain

```
## DF <anything>
```

or else end with

```
<something> # DF <anything>
```

Then print from `DF` onwards

Here are some examples

```
  local lbpos=21    # DF [LBPOS]  Label Position
  local ktg="PILE"  # DF [KTG]    Category
  ## DF [KARG]   Control Argument
  Some text
  printf '%s\n' "$@"  \
      | while IFS="" read -r lnp; do  # DF [LNP]  Line Input
  More text
```

Result

```
DF [LBPOS]  Label Position
DF [KTG]    Category
DF [KARG]   Control Argument
DF [LNP]  Line Input
```

Comment: When you say _"or else end with"_ do you mean the exclusive-OR? Which is to say, you don't expect both a starting `## DF` and an internal (`# DF`) within the same line? Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ sed -n -e 's/.*# DF */DF /p' /tmp/df.txt 
DF [LBPOS]  Label Position
DF [KTG]    Category
DF [KARG]   Control Argument
DF [LNP]  Line Input
```

If the spaces in your input file might be tabs instead of (or as well as) spaces, use `[[:blank:]]` instead of just a space.  `[[:blank:]]` matches any horizontal whitespace.  For example (using `sed`'s `-E` option for Extended Regular Expressions, ERE, instead of the default Basic Regular Expressions, BRE, so that we can use the `+` quantifier):

```
sed -n -E 's/.*#[[:blank:]]+DF[[:blank:]]+/DF /p' /tmp/df.txt
```

Comment: If I have the command in a bash script, how can I print the result on terminal?

Comment: Have been trying to fix the problem of using a dynamic pattern in bash.  `ptrn=".*# DF *" ; sed -n -e 's/$ptrn/DF /p' "$1"` does not print any matches.

Comment: Variable interpolation does not happen inside single quotes. Use **double quotes** around the sed script, e.g.  `sed -nE "s/$ptrn/DF /p" "$1"`.  Be careful about the contents of the $ptrn variable, it's quite easy to break a sed script (e.g. invalid regex, or if it contains a `/` or whatever you use as the delimiter).   Alternatively, use awk or perl and pass the search pattern to the script as an arg or as a variable - e.g. `perl -ne 'BEGIN {$p=shift}; print if s/$p/DF /' "$ptrn" /tmp/df.txt`.  You could pass the replacement string too if you wanted.

Comment: As for printing on the terminal, printing to stdout is the default for sed (and many other tools) - the example above was copy-pasted directly from my terminal.  To do otherwise, you need to redirect to another file or use command substitution to capture the output into a variable.

Answer (score 2):

With a `GNU` `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '# \KDF .*' file
DF [LBPOS]  Label Position
DF [KTG]    Category
DF [KARG]   Control Argument
DF [LNP]  Line Input
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the two variants of patterns literally, you would end up with a `sed` script that consists of the following two instructions:

```
s/^## \(DF \)/\1/p
s/..* # \(DF \)/\1/p
```

The first of these replaces `## DF <anything>` at the start of the line with `DF <anything>`, where `<anything>` is assumed to be a possibly empty string of any length.

The second instruction replaces `<something> # DF <anything>` by `DF <anything>` where `<something>` is assumed to be a non-empty string of any length. The basic regular expression `..*` is the same as `.\{1,\}`, which is the same as the extended regular expression `.{1,}`, which is the same as `.+`, i.e. a pattern that matches one or more characters.

Testing (the test data is taken from the question, but the first few space characters on each line were removed):

```bash
$ sed -n -e 's/^## \(DF \)/\1/p' -e 's/..* # \(DF \)/\1/p'  file
DF [LBPOS]  Label Position
DF [KTG]    Category
DF [KARG]   Control Argument
DF [LNP]  Line Input
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put $/  if m/ ^ "## " <( DF .* )> $ || .+ "# " <( DF .* )> $ /;'  file
    
#OR
    
~$ raku -ne 'put $<> if m/ ^ "## " <( DF .* )> $ || .+ "# " <( DF .* )> $ /;'  file
```

Above are answers coded in Raku, a member of the Perl family of programming languages. Raku features (among other things) high-level support for Unicode, and rational numbers built-in.

Briefly, a `m/ /` match is first sought for a beginning-of-string `"## "`,  followed by `<( DF .* )>`, i.e. "DF" followed by one-or-more characters, or `||` secondarily for one-or-more characters followed by an internal `"# "`, followed by `<( DF .* )>`, i.e. "DF" followed by zero-or-more characters.

Raku's `<(`...`)>` capture markers drop all recognition elements outside the markers. If a match is found only the `$/` (or $<>`) match-variable is returned, which drops non-matching lines.

Sample Input:

```
local lbpos=21    # DF [LBPOS]  Label Position
local ktg="PILE"  # DF [KTG]    Category
## DF [KARG]   Control Argument
Some text
printf '%s\n' "$@"  \
      | while IFS="" read -r lnp; do  # DF [LNP]  Line Input
More text
```

Sample Output:

```
DF [LBPOS]  Label Position
DF [KTG]    Category
DF [KARG]   Control Argument
DF [LNP]  Line Input
```

https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org